# Merge two while loops in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

I'm trying to implement the motion sensor and pulse sensor together in the raspberry pi.
I'm new in python and I have tried to merge them, but only the motion sensor work.

Here is the code for the PIR moiton sensor (PIR.py):

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN) #PIR
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT) #BUzzer

try:
    time.sleep(2) # to stabilize sensor
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(23):
            GPIO.output(24, True)
            time.sleep(0.5) #Buzzer turns on for 0.5 sec
            GPIO.output(24, False)
            print("Motion Detected...")
            time.sleep(5) #to avoid multiple detection
        time.sleep(0.1) #loop delay, should be less than detection delay

except:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

And the code for the pulse sensor (heartBeats.py):

```
# Simple heart beat reader for Raspberry pi using ADS1x15 family of ADCs and a pulse sensor - http://pulsesensor.com/.
# The code borrows heavily from Tony DiCola's examples of using ADS1x15 with 
# Raspberry pi and WorldFamousElectronics's code for PulseSensor_Amped_Arduino

# Author: Udayan Kumar
# License: Public Domain

import time
# Import the ADS1x15 module.
import Adafruit_ADS1x15


if __name__ == '__main__':

    adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015()
    # initialization 
    GAIN = 2/3  
    curState = 0
    thresh = 525  # mid point in the waveform
    P = 512
    T = 512
    stateChanged = 0
    sampleCounter = 0
    lastBeatTime = 0
    firstBeat = True
    secondBeat = False
    Pulse = False
    IBI = 600
    rate = [0]*10
    amp = 100

    lastTime = int(time.time()*1000)

    # Main loop. use Ctrl-c to stop the code
    while True:
        # read from the ADC
        Signal = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)   #TODO: Select the correct ADC channel. I have selected A0 here
        curTime = int(time.time()*1000)

        sampleCounter += curTime - lastTime;      #                   # keep track of the time in mS with this variable
        lastTime = curTime
        N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;     #  # monitor the time since the last beat to avoid noise
        #print N, Signal, curTime, sampleCounter, lastBeatTime

        ##  find the peak and trough of the pulse wave
        if Signal < thresh and N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0 :  #       # avoid dichrotic noise by waiting 3/5 of last IBI
            if Signal < T :                        # T is the trough
              T = Signal;                         # keep track of lowest point in pulse wave 

        if Signal > thresh and  Signal > P:           # thresh condition helps avoid noise
            P = Signal;                             # P is the peak
                                                # keep track of highest point in pulse wave

          #  NOW IT'S TIME TO LOOK FOR THE HEART BEAT
          # signal surges up in value every time there is a pulse
        if N > 250 :                                   # avoid high frequency noise
            if  (Signal > thresh) and  (Pulse == False) and  (N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0)  :       
              Pulse = True;                               # set the Pulse flag when we think there is a pulse
              IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;         # measure time between beats in mS
              lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;               # keep track of time for next pulse

              if secondBeat :                        # if this is the second beat, if secondBeat == TRUE
                secondBeat = False;                  # clear secondBeat flag
                for i in range(0,10):             # seed the running total to get a realisitic BPM at startup
                  rate[i] = IBI;                      

              if firstBeat :                        # if it's the first time we found a beat, if firstBeat == TRUE
                firstBeat = False;                   # clear firstBeat flag
                secondBeat = True;                   # set the second beat flag
                continue                              # IBI value is unreliable so discard it


              # keep a running total of the last 10 IBI values
              runningTotal = 0;                  # clear the runningTotal variable    

              for i in range(0,9):                # shift data in the rate array
                rate[i] = rate[i+1];                  # and drop the oldest IBI value 
                runningTotal += rate[i];              # add up the 9 oldest IBI values

              rate[9] = IBI;                          # add the latest IBI to the rate array
              runningTotal += rate[9];                # add the latest IBI to runningTotal
              runningTotal /= 10;                     # average the last 10 IBI values 
              BPM = 60000/runningTotal;               # how many beats can fit into a minute? that's BPM!
              print 'BPM: {}'.format(BPM)

        if Signal < thresh and Pulse == True :   # when the values are going down, the beat is over
            Pulse = False;                         # reset the Pulse flag so we can do it again
            amp = P - T;                           # get amplitude of the pulse wave
            thresh = amp/2 + T;                    # set thresh at 50% of the amplitude
            P = thresh;                            # reset these for next time
            T = thresh;

        if N > 2500 :                          # if 2.5 seconds go by without a beat
            thresh = 512;                          # set thresh default
            P = 512;                               # set P default
            T = 512;                               # set T default
            lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;          # bring the lastBeatTime up to date        
            firstBeat = True;                      # set these to avoid noise
            secondBeat = False;                    # when we get the heartbeat back
            print "no beats found"

        time.sleep(0.005)
```

I would like the output would look like the following:

```
Motion Detected...
BPM: 54

BPM: 53

Motion Detected...
no beats found
```

Thank you for your help.

Update 1: I tried to use the functions to run the sensor together, however, I have to force the compiler to stop (ctrl + C) in order to move to the next function.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import time
# Import the ADS1x15 module.
import Adafruit_ADS1x15


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN) #PIR
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT) #BUzzer

def pir_function():
            print("This is the motion sensor")

try:
    time.sleep(2) # to stabilize sensor
    while True:
        if GPIO.input(23):
            GPIO.output(24, True)
            time.sleep(0.5) #Buzzer turns on for 0.5 sec
            GPIO.output(24, False)
            print("Motion Detected...")
            time.sleep(5) #to avoid multiple detection
        time.sleep(0.1) #loop delay, should be less than detection delay

except:
    GPIO.cleanup()


def heart_function():

    adc = Adafruit_ADS1x15.ADS1015()
    # initialization 
    GAIN = 2/3  
    curState = 0
    thresh = 525  # mid point in the waveform
    P = 512
    T = 512
    stateChanged = 0
    sampleCounter = 0
    lastBeatTime = 0
    firstBeat = True
    secondBeat = False
    Pulse = False
    IBI = 600
    rate = [0]*10
    amp = 100

    lastTime = int(time.time()*1000)

    # Main loop. use Ctrl-c to stop the code
    while True:
        # read from the ADC
        Signal = adc.read_adc(0, gain=GAIN)   #TODO: Select the correct ADC channel. I have selected A0 here
        curTime = int(time.time()*1000)

        sampleCounter += curTime - lastTime;      #                   # keep track of the time in mS with this variable
        lastTime = curTime
        N = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;     #  # monitor the time since the last beat to avoid noise
        #print N, Signal, curTime, sampleCounter, lastBeatTime

        ##  find the peak and trough of the pulse wave
        if Signal < thresh and N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0 :  #       # avoid dichrotic noise by waiting 3/5 of last IBI
            if Signal < T :                        # T is the trough
              T = Signal;                         # keep track of lowest point in pulse wave 

        if Signal > thresh and  Signal > P:           # thresh condition helps avoid noise
            P = Signal;                             # P is the peak
                                                # keep track of highest point in pulse wave

          #  NOW IT'S TIME TO LOOK FOR THE HEART BEAT
          # signal surges up in value every time there is a pulse
        if N > 250 :                                   # avoid high frequency noise
            if  (Signal > thresh) and  (Pulse == False) and  (N > (IBI/5.0)*3.0)  :       
              Pulse = True;                               # set the Pulse flag when we think there is a pulse
              IBI = sampleCounter - lastBeatTime;         # measure time between beats in mS
              lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;               # keep track of time for next pulse

              if secondBeat :                        # if this is the second beat, if secondBeat == TRUE
                secondBeat = False;                  # clear secondBeat flag
                for i in range(0,10):             # seed the running total to get a realisitic BPM at startup
                  rate[i] = IBI;                      

              if firstBeat :                        # if it's the first time we found a beat, if firstBeat == TRUE
                firstBeat = False;                   # clear firstBeat flag
                secondBeat = True;                   # set the second beat flag
                continue                              # IBI value is unreliable so discard it


              # keep a running total of the last 10 IBI values
              runningTotal = 0;                  # clear the runningTotal variable    

              for i in range(0,9):                # shift data in the rate array
                rate[i] = rate[i+1];                  # and drop the oldest IBI value 
                runningTotal += rate[i];              # add up the 9 oldest IBI values

              rate[9] = IBI;                          # add the latest IBI to the rate array
              runningTotal += rate[9];                # add the latest IBI to runningTotal
              runningTotal /= 10;                     # average the last 10 IBI values 
              BPM = 60000/runningTotal;               # how many beats can fit into a minute? that's BPM!
              print 'BPM: {}'.format(BPM)

        if Signal < thresh and Pulse == True :   # when the values are going down, the beat is over
            Pulse = False;                         # reset the Pulse flag so we can do it again
            amp = P - T;                           # get amplitude of the pulse wave
            thresh = amp/2 + T;                    # set thresh at 50% of the amplitude
            P = thresh;                            # reset these for next time
            T = thresh;

        if N > 2500 :                          # if 2.5 seconds go by without a beat
            thresh = 512;                          # set thresh default
            P = 512;                               # set P default
            T = 512;                               # set T default
            lastBeatTime = sampleCounter;          # bring the lastBeatTime up to date        
            firstBeat = True;                      # set these to avoid noise
            secondBeat = False;                    # when we get the heartbeat back
            print "no beats found"

        time.sleep(0.005)





pir_function()
heart_function()
```

Comment: I would use [trio-gpio](https://github.com/python-trio/trio-gpio/blob/master/examples/line_echo_polled.py).

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention how you are running your program.  I'm assuming

```
 python heartBeats.py
```

This will run *heartbeats.py* only.  It doesn't include *PIR.py*, so that code will never be executed.  I'm assuming that you want both loops to be run, more or less at the same time, or alternating.

A simple approach would be to create two functions "heartBeat" and "motionDetect", each of which performs a single iteration of the loop in heartBeats.py and PIR.py and then returns.  In main, call these in a loop:

```
while True:
  heartBeat()
  motionDetect()
```

A more complicated approach would be to create two threads, one to run the PIR code the other to run the heartBeats code.

Comment: Thanks. Never thought of it. I'll try it out

Comment: We don't use `;` in Python.

Comment: take a look to asyncio to run the two functions in parallel

Comment: Oops.  I've been programming in PHP all week and it took me most of that time to add ; on every line.  Now can't stop.

Comment: I tried to use the functions to run the sensor together, however, I have to force the compiler to stop (ctrl + C) in order to move to the next function.

Comment: I'm guessing that you kept the loops in the heartBeat() and motionDetect() functions.  Remove the loops and just have the body from the loop in the function.